# InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [3,256,256,2] vs. [3,150,150,2]

Tags: python, image, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I want to build a model to colorize the image, I tried to execute this code but I faced Incompatible shapes: [3,256,256,2] vs. [3,150,150,2] error.

```
#CNN model

from keras.layers import Conv2D, Conv2DTranspose, UpSampling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dense, Dropout, Flatten, InputLayer
from tensorflow.keras.layers import (
    BatchNormalization, SeparableConv2D, MaxPooling2D, Activation, Flatten, Dropout, Dense
)
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard, ModelCheckpoint
from keras.models import Sequential

model = Sequential()

#Input Layer
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), input_shape=(256, 256, 1), activation='relu', padding='same'))

#Hidden Layers
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', strides=2))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', strides=2))
model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', strides=2))
model.add(Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(UpSampling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(UpSampling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(2, (3, 3), activation='tanh', padding='same'))
model.add(UpSampling2D((2, 2)))



#Compiling the CNN
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='mse', metrics = ['accuracy'])
#model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

the error occurs when I run the code to fit the model

```
# Image transformer
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        rotation_range=20,
        horizontal_flip=True)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Image transformer
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        rotation_range=20,
        horizontal_flip=True)

# Generate training data
batch_size = 10
def image_a_b_gen(batch_size):
    for batch in datagen.flow(Xtrain, batch_size=batch_size ):
        lab_batch = rgb2lab(batch)
        X_batch = lab_batch[:,:,:,0]
        Y_batch = lab_batch[:,:,:,1:] / 128
        yield (X_batch.reshape(X_batch.shape+(1,)), Y_batch)


        # Train model      
tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir="/output/beta_run")
trainedmodel = model.fit(image_a_b_gen(batch_size), callbacks=[tensorboard],epochs=100, steps_per_epoch=30)
```

Error message:

```
 InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-112-7a987e785f95> in <module>
         29         # Train model
         30 tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir="/output/beta_run")
    ---> 31 trainedmodel = model.fit(image_a_b_gen(batch_size), callbacks=[tensorboard],epochs=100, steps_per_epoch=30)
         32 
         33 
    
    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
         65     except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
         66       filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
    ---> 67       raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
         68     finally:
         69       del filtered_tb
    
    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
         56   try:
         57     ctx.ensure_initialized()
    ---> 58     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
         59                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
         60   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
    
    InvalidArgumentError:  Incompatible shapes: [3,256,256,2] vs. [3,150,150,2]
         [[node gradient_tape/mean_squared_error/BroadcastGradientArgs
     (defined at C:\Users\HudaA\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\optimizer_v2\optimizer_v2.py:464)
    ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_33345]
```

I tried to print the summarize of layers but I could not find the problem

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the error.

1. The expected output from your model, for an input like (3,256,256,1) is (3,256,256,2).
2. The trace shows that something is messing up with the mse (loss function) part of things.

Solution :

Check the shape of X_batch.reshape(X_batch.shape+(1,) and Y_batch as output from the function image_a_b_gen.

My guess is that your Y_batch is not of the correct shape.

Comment: I checked the shape of X_batch and Y_batch, it is (150,150,1) which is the dimension of the images in the dataset. could you help me How can I change the parameters of the layers to fit my dataset?